# How to trigger nested count update after deleting nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this callback that update the total amount summing all nested objects amounts. This is working nice when adding new payment items.

```
before_save :update_payment_total

def update_payment_total
  self.amount_cents = self.payment_items.sum(:total_payout_cents)
end
```

The problem is when editing a Payment and deleting payment items the `before_save` is not triggered I presume because the payment_items are deleted after this callback is call.

When try to use after_save instead and set some save or update_attributes I get `stack level too deep`

Any idea how to update count based on the new saved payment items only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used `after_commit` instead and so I can avoid the `stack level too deep`.